# matching urls with query string

Tags: php, url

I need a piece of code that basically does task of matching URL. I have listed 2 scenarios below to clear how I need the things.

Match URL may/may not contain sub-directory, so there are 2 scenarios.

```
http://example.com/?pgid=1
http://example.com/?pgid=1&opt2=2
http://example.com/?opt2=2&pgid=1
http://example.com/?pgid=1&opt2=2&opt3=3
http://example.com/?opt2=2&pgid=1&opt3=3
http://example.com/?opt2=2&opt3=3&pgid=1

should match => http://example.com/?pgid=1
```

and

```
http://example.com/sub-dir/?pgid=1
http://example.com/sub-dir/?pgid=1&opt2=2
http://example.com/sub-dir/?opt2=2&pgid=1
http://example.com/sub-dir/?pgid=1&opt2=2&opt3=3
http://example.com/sub-dir/?opt2=2&pgid=1&opt3=3
http://example.com/sub-dir/?opt2=2&opt3=3&pgid=1

should match => http://example.com/sub-dir/?pgid=1
```

How can I achieve above thing, help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wont you first bother to tell us what you have done to address your needs ?

Comment: This'll match all your URLs: `.*` (I.e. I agree with @Bhaskar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to mach that url is: `\?pgid=1$`

As i understand you don't want any other query string parameters in your url.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean something like this:

```
$input = array('http://example.com/?pgid=1',
               'http://example.com/?pgid=1&opt2=2',
               'http://example.com/?opt2=2&opt3=3&pgid=1',
               'http://example.com/sub-dir/?opt2=2&opt3=3&pgid=1');


foreach($input as $i){

    $url = parse_url($i);
    echo $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'];
    parse_str($url['query'],$query);
    echo 'pgid='.$query['pgid'];
    echo '<br/>';

}
```

Obviously you should adjust this to your personal needs, but this shows how you can extract `pgid` and rebuild the url with just that parameter.

Afterwards you can do the matching, probably by just using `$query['pgid']` or maybe by using the whole new url.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/?pgid=1&opt2=2&opt3=3');
$against = parse_url('http://example.com/?pgid=1');

$folder = $url['path'];
$query = parse_str($url['query']);
$pgidout = $pgid;
$query = parse_str($against['query']);


if(($url['path'] == $against['path']) && ($pgid == $pgidout)){
    echo "matched";
} else {
    echo "not matched";
}
```